# How to update multiple occurrence a specific value of a object present in array of object within Postgres JSON Field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Here is my JSON field where has multiple users with the same name. I want to update all users whose name is **Devang** to **Dev**

JSON

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "user_name": "Devang",
            "user_weight": 0.7676846955248864
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Meet",
            "user_weight": 0.07447325861051013
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Devang",
            "user_weight": 0.056163873153859706
        }
    ],
    "address": [
        {
            "address_name": "India"
        }
    ]
}
```

After Update The JSON would be

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "user_name": "Dev",
            "user_weight": 0.7676846955248864
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Meet",
            "user_weight": 0.07447325861051013
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Dev",
            "user_weight": 0.056163873153859706
        }
    ],
    "address": [
        {
            "address_name": "India"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I have tried this query but update only the first occurrence due to subquery.

```
with cte as (
  select  id,  ('{user,'||index-1||',user_name}')::text[] as json_path
  from user_table, jsonb_array_elements(json_field->'user') 
  with ordinality arr(vals,index) where arr.vals->>'user_name' ='Devang'
  )

 update user_table 
set json_field = jsonb_set(json_field,cte.json_path,'"Dev"',false) 
 from cte where user_table.id=cte.id;
```

Please also look at this [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8a2acd961ab6e0e2e568f932268564cb)

Any answer will be appreciated

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use string function REPLACE:

```sql
UPDATE user_table
SET json_field = REPLACE(json_field :: TEXT, '"user_name": "Devang"', '"user_name": "Dev"') :: JSONB;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fa36275977f85a1233bcbec150ada266

Comment: what if I want to remove those object whose user_name is devang

Comment: Abandon JSONB altogether and use normalized structure with a couple of tables joined by foreign keys. Then the operations you need will be very simple.